# How to sum the values inside dictionary if the values in the form of list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'Key1':[99,98,97],'Key2':[89,82,85]}
```

how to sum the values of key1 in python3 if the values in the format of list.

Comment: Could you add the expected result ?, it will be easier to understand what exactly do you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use sum() on the dict[key] e.g.

```
dict1 = {'Key1':[99,98,97],'Key2':[89,82,85]}

r = sum(dict1['Key1'])
print(r)
>> 294
```

Or if you mean you want to sum the first key of the dict, not necessarily 'Key1' then you can do it in a loop

```
dict1 = {'Key1':[99,98,97],'Key2':[89,82,85]}

for _, val_list in dict1.items(): # loop over list
    r = sum(val_list) # sum the list
    break

print(r)
>> 294
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Actually I got the error through dict1.values() in loop. That is solved now.